# Name of the $(-1)^n$ function?

Tags: analysis, functions, exponentiation

Does the function $f\left(n\right)=\left(-1\right)^n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ used in a lot of mathematical formulas have a special name ?

EDIT: The context of this question is that I need a name for this function in a software.

Comment: I've always thought of it as the "alternating signs function" ;p

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. I don't think it is used often enough to be deserving of a special name, either (the only times I have ever saw it used are in real analysis sequences or series textbook/exam questions).

Comment: It may be "parity function", as for me.

Comment: Note that $\cos(\pi\, n)$ is a reasonably succinct continuous extension.

Comment: "sequence of alternating signs".

Comment: To clarify, this is a sequence, not a function. Not trying to nitpick or anything, but since this question is about terminology I figured it's worth noting.

Comment: @ZettaSuro A sequence is a function whose domain is the natural numbers.

Comment: @GitGud I know that. But if it had a name it would be called "the _____ sequence" rather than "the ______ function" so if the OP had tried to search for a name for it, looking for the name of a function would have turned up blank.

Comment: @ZettaSuro Just saying you should instead say something like *it's more than a function, it's a sequence*.

Comment: "The flippy-floppy function"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. One just writes it out like that, for example, $$\sum (-1)^n\cdot a^n$$

not $$\sum \operatorname{some\;name}(n)\cdot a^n$$

Just imagine how cumbersome things would get!

**ADD** If you need a name for it, choose a sensible one and make it clear. I'd take $\text{alt}(n)$.

Comment: I think the OP means a name just to orally pronounce the function and not the way you're assuming. For instance you call the characteristic function, characteristic function, but you don't write $\text{characteristic function}(x)$.

Comment: @GitGud I think not, else he would say "How does one read $(-1)^n$ out loud?" or something of the sort. In this case, it seems the OP is asking for a name, as in $\sin,\cos$, &c.

Comment: Actually I need a name for this function for a software.

Comment: @Vincent Are you just wondering if there's a widely accepted name so you can name the function in your program?

Comment: @GitGud I need a short name that is sufficiently expressive to be understood.

Comment: @GitGud how about m1tt(n) ?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Did you mean to message the OP?

Comment: my apologies gitGud, the comment was meant at @Vincent